# Mapping printers using Group Policy Preferences; works on Windows XP, not on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, print-server, network-printer, windows-server-2003-r2

I'm trying to use Group Policy Preferences to manage user connections to shared printers.

The print server is Windows Server 2003 R2 Std edition. Several printers are installed, and I've added x64 editions of all the drivers to the print server as well.

I've created a new GPO containing the printer preference settings. Printer mappings are targeted based on AD security group membership.

I log on to a Windows XP PC with the Group Policy CSEs installed and the printer maps perfectly.

I log on to a Windows 7 x64 PC and it doesn't map. If I manually connect to the shared printer, I get a prompt which asks me to confirm if I trust the server before installing the driver, and then it works perfectly.

I have domain admin rights and my UAC settings have not been changed from the default, i.e. UAC is enabled and the default level is selected.

Is the printer mapping failing because it's unable to prompt me to install the driver, or is there something else afoot?

Comment: what exactly do you mean in '.. and my UAC settings are untouched' Have you disabled UAC?

Comment: I have not changed the UAC settings from the defaults. Edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but are the 64 bit drivers installed on your print server?

Comment: @Zoredache: yes, I said that in the question. I'll update the wording to make it clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK I managed to get this working.

For Vista there is a Group Policy setting (more info [here](http://ts2blogs.com/blogs/rwagg/archive/2008/05/22/eliminate-uac-for-printer-driver-installation.aspx)):

- User Configuration/Policies/Admin Templates/Control Panel/Printers

Configuring the "Point and Print Restrictions" policy setting to "Disabled" will allow for silent printer driver installation, and thus allow the printer to be mapped successfully.

After struggling for the better part of this morning trying to figure out why this didn't work on Windows 7, I eventually discovered that Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2 ignore this policy setting. There is an equivalent setting under:

- Computer Configuration/Policies/Admin Templates/Printers

This is honoured by Windows 7 and Server 2008 R2 See [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753269.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find the policy under Computer Configuration, you may not be using Group Policy Management on Server 2008 R2. You'll only get the policy on Server 2003 if you have updated your ADM files to the latest.

If you are having the reverse problem with XP clients, make sure you have followed this article:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888046

Method 1 worked for me.