# Printer deployment via Group Policy not working on a single system

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, group-policy, printing

One of my coworkers just got a new laptop running Windows 7 Pro x64. We use a GPO to deploy the printers to every system, but for some reason it is not working on this system.

I have been breaking my head over this for the past 3 hours now without any result.
The strange thing is that `gpresult /H` seems to indicate that the GPO did run.

**The hardware:**

- Laptop: Windows 7 Professional x64
- Print server: Windows Server 2008 x64 R1
- HP Color LaserJet 2605dn
- HP LaserJet P2015
- Driver packages on server: HP universal printer driver PCL5, both X86 as X64

**Oddities and other info:**

- GPO working flawlessly on every other system, including my own Windows 7 Ultimate X64 laptop
- `gpresult /H` shows the GPO being ran
- Windows Firewall completely disabled on the new laptop

Below is the **output for `gpresult /H`** (in Dutch sadly, but I think you'll recognize it):

```
Beleidsregels
Windows-instellingen
Printerverbindingen
Pad Dominerend groepsbeleidsobject
\\Server2008\HP Color LaserJet 2605dn   Printers
\\Server2008\HP LaserJet P2015  Printers
Beheersjablonen
Beleidsdefinities (ADMX-bestanden) opgehaald van de lokale computer.
Configuratiescherm/Printers
Beleid  Instelling  Dominerend groepsbeleidsobject
Beperkingen van point-and-print Uitgeschakeld   Printers
```

Like I said, I have been trying to figure this out for the past few hours or so without any result, so you are my last hope.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Is the driver already installed on the Clients?  I am thinking that perhaps the users do not have permissions to install the initial driver and that is causing the addition to silently fail.

update:

If they don't exist already on the client you need to ensure that the point and print restrictions are set to allow silent driver installation. In a mixed environment (both win 7 and prior clients) you need to set it in both User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Control Panel\Printers and Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Printers.

set it to not show the elevation prompt

Comment: No it is not. The driver packages reside on a shared folder on the server which should be readable to all users. Is there any way to check this?

Comment: See my update for more details.  If it's not installed there are additional GP settings

Answer (score 1):

See if my previous answer on this helps: [Mapping printers using Group Policy Preferences; works on Windows XP, not on Windows 7 x64](https://serverfault.com/questions/76706/mapping-printers-using-group-policy-preferences-works-on-windows-xp-not-on-wind/77104#77104)

Comment: I have set this user policy, but for some reason, it is not showing under the 'computer configuration' section.

Comment: Are you editing the GPO from a Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 *R2* machine? The policy setting under Computer Configuration did not exist in older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off UAC on the affected computer and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Something I haven't tried yet; could it make the difference? My own computer is using UAC as well and works fine...

Comment: Tried this now, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

Check the group policy event logs on the effected machine.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749336%28WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having this issue. Have you tried this [MS fix](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-US;2388142)?

Answer (score 0):

Try browsing on the client machine to the print server (eg \\Server2008\ ). Ensure the client machine can see the shared printers, then try right clicking one and choosing "Connect". See if the printer maps OK or if there are any prompts/driver issues etc.