# Add printer as domain user in Windows 7

Tags: security, windows-7, network-printer, authorization, drivers

In Windows 7, one has to have (local) administrator privileges to install a printer driver, even when this printer is installed from one of the domain servers.

The only 'solution' I've read so far is to add the user to the local admin group.

This is not something I like to do, because that means they can install a whole lot of other software (toolbars, malware) as well. So is there another way to allow a user to install a printer driver (and still not allowing them to install trash)?

Update: the server is running windows server 2003

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my similar question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/76706/).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a useful Microsoft TechNet article: [Control Printer Driver Installation Security](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753269.aspx)

Follow the instructions and read the note at the bottom of the page:

> To disable driver installation warning messages and elevation prompts on computers that are running Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2, in the Point and Print Restrictions dialog box, click Disabled, and then click OK. This setting disables the enhanced printer driver installation security of Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I forgot to mention that we're using Windows Server 2003. So I guess that won't work there.